# Some error in SO while linking images

Tags: support, images

Today, I needed to visit my earlier question for some reason. In doing so, I saw a minor error in SO url management for rendering Images. The question i posted had an image, but now it doesn't appear and says the link is broken. Earlier when the question was posted this was working fine. Also, I have seen many question in SO over the last two days that are unable to render the image posted in the questions.

Is there an error of some sort in the code of SO. If so, I would like the moderators and developer attention to this. The question i am talking about is the following :

[Managing CSS floats in dynamic scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702131/managing-css-floats-in-dynamic-scenarios)

[Displaying List elements in Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671895/displaying-list-elements-in-razor-view)

Comment: Currently gravarar.com and imgur.com appears to be down, at least for people from certain countries. I believe it will be fixed soon and anyway it's out of our control.

Comment: ohh k....ya i was going to mention gravatar.com too......thanks mate

Comment: It's back on track now.

Comment: hmm....ya it is.....good and thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see gravatar and imgur problems as well; they seem to not appear in my ISP's DNS server anymore. Manually choosing one of Google's DNS servers, I get both gravatar and imgur.

There was a [huge attack on the DNS system in Brazil yesterday](http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/major-dns-cache-poisoning-attack-hits-brazilian-isps-110711); I wouln't be surprised if this was related.

Either way, this is out of our control.

**Edit:** A [twitter search](http://twitter.com/#!/search/edgecast%20dns) reveals that Edgecast seems to have DNS issues. This affects both Gravatar and imgur, since they both use Edgecast.

Comment: Thanks, thought it's just our local servers. Seems like more "global" problem then.