# avatar images don't work

Tags: bug, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some error in SO while linking images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111509/some-error-in-so-while-linking-images)

This might be just my machine but are the avatars working ?

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript

I am on the newest tab, and all of the avatars don't work.

here is a link of one of the avatars

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f394b822c935303424f4c2ac1ad64831?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG

if you need more info ... let me know.

Comment: Confirmed, Gravatar seems to be down for me, too. (Not SO's fault though)

Comment: I think it's gravatar's website is not working at all, not even pinging, all wordpress people who use gravatar have same problem :) http://wordpress.org/support/topic/gravatarcom-down

Comment: @Val that linked topic is 6 years old :/

Comment: It's back... :)

Comment: @Dunhamzzz that link was meant to show wordpress has the same problem with gravatars, :)

Comment: ....6 years ago. Also FYI Gravatar is owned by the people behind WP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) that Gravatar uses is down.

Notably, this has also affected WordPress.org and imgur.com - there are probably others.

This will be sorted when the server admins wake up.

Comment: I'm really really surprised they don't have any backup server!